# How is a maven artifactid connected to a file?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifact

I experimented with webservices and jboss4 for the last couple of days, and I stumbled over the following problem:

I included this dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As it turned out, this caused JBoss4 to fail with the error message

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find endpoint meta data

Until I added the tiny little line

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

to the dependency. I now understand that this problem was caused by the fact, that JBoss4 brings this library himself, and that it is the double inclusion of the same library (probably 2 different versions) that caused this. But now, when I look into the JBoss lib folder I see the following files:

```
commons-codec.jar
commons-httpclient.jar
commons-logging.jar
concurrent.jar
endorsed
getopt.jar
jboss-common.jar
jboss-jmx.jar
jboss-system.jar
jboss-xml-binding.jar
log4j-boot.jar
```

How do I know which jars correspond to which maven artifact? How do I know for any of the million files in my .m2/repository folder which groupid, artifactid and version number they belong to?

Comment: The maven repository is structured based on `groupId/artifactId/version` which results in the folder structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the jar files in provided/included by Jboss are not related to maven. They are there just for the sake for jboss it self to run. Other application who wants to run in the container need to provide they own sets of library. BUT, some time, some of the library provided by JBoss is enough for the application (since they will live on the same VM), so you dont need to provide your own. You use those provided library for your development purpose, and later, when you deploy, you dont include them in your deployment.

So, there are no telling which Jar, provided by JBOSS should relate to which artifactId or groupId or version in the maven repositories, unless for some hint on their names.

For example, if you see that Jboss brings "commons-codec.jar" with it. There are no telling that the jar comes from which artifactId or groupId or version in Maven. You may guess that "commons-codec" should be a name of some artifact. Sites like http://mvnrepository.com/ helps you to find what related maven artifact that may relate to the jar you are investigating.

Answer (score 1):

The artefact name is always ${artifactId}-${version}.${type}
in your case : `jboss-jaxws-4.2.2.jar`.

You're just looking for it in the bad place, the `lib` folder you're talking about must be the one of the unified classloader, the library you're looking for must be loaded by the server classloader i.e. it must reside in `JBOSS_HOME/modules`

[**edit**]
Ferdinand Neman is right when he says that jboss is not related to maven. Dependencies declaration in pom just allows maven to build and package your project. The runtime behavior depends on your targeted environment, the only things to ensure is that your dependencies must be resolved during classloading whether because they are packaged with your project or provided by the runtime environment.

Anyway the jar jboss-jaxws-4.2.2.jar will necessary be present on your workstation (in the local maven repository) to allow class linkage during maven compilation, as the jar is marked as provided it will not be included in the resulting build artefact.

Comment: There is no folder "modules" in my JBoss directory, however I think you're right, as there is a "client" folder containing a "jboss-jaxws.jar". 
Am I looking in the right place now?

Comment: Well, i don't know jboss-4 the 'osgi sub-system' probably came in later versions.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very useful as well: I am sure knowing the name of any artifact built with maven will be very helpful in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find useful this maven command

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

It shows you jar dependencies, classified by group-artifact and it also represents dependencies between them as a tree.